Numerical Sequence Puzzle: 8388607, 536870911, 2147483647,?
Sequence puzzle made by me. 8388607, 536870911, 2147483647, ?

Nice idea!

 The answer is 137438953471


 These are all the maximum UNSIGNED INTEGERS for bit values ascending in the order of primes 23 bit, 29 bit, 31 bit and so 37 bit which is 137438953471!
 


Not sure I understand the explanation here. The first two values are both (2^n)-1, but the third is 2^n.

Is this clearer

This chart was from a chat bot.

Ah yes I think the OP made a mistake with the last digit of the 3 number

That still doesn't explain why the third value is 2147483648

The bits are going up the prime number sequence

Damn I just realised these are marsenne numbers where p is prime

What is the pattern in 23, 27, 31? And those are not Mersenne primes. Btw, I see you have changed the question too.

ACB let me link you what I found. https://oeis.org/A001348

Pattern is that in the prime number sequence the primes are going up +1, +1.
